# How to create a new table with "default value column" depending on the tables I select from?

Tags: mysql, database, insert, create-table

Let's say, I have two tables, one for "sales" and another for "stock".

Sales table would be like this:

```
-------------------------
| location | item | qty |
------------------------
|    1     |  11  |  1  |
|    2     |  12  |  1  |
-------------------------
```

And stock table would look like this:

```
-------------------------
| location | item | qty |
------------------------
|    1     |  11  |  90 |
|    2     |  12  |  70 |
-------------------------
```

I want to insert the data from both tables for items "11" and "12" in a new table, and separating between them with "sales" and "stock" in a new column called "type" like this:

```
---------------------------------
| type  | location | item | qty |
---------------------------------
| sales |    1     |  11  |  1  |
| sales |    2     |  12  |  1  |
| stock |    1     |  11  |  90 |
| stock |    2     |  12  |  70 |
---------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dude really? U can pound that out

Comment: Here is a hint two insert stmts ignoring using a union

Comment: @AsConfused, my problem is with adding default "sales" and "stock", not with union or insert.

Comment: So it is the first column that is a problem. How can u solve that?

Comment: Yes, @AsConfused. It's.

Comment: So hard code the first column in your select stmt

Comment: And how that, @AsConfused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    insert into table3 (thetype,location,item,qty) select 'sales',location,item,qty 
from sales where item in (11,12)


    insert into table3 (thetype,location,item,qty) select 'stock',location,item,qty 
from stock where item in (11,12)
```